# RelativeLayout background always displayed black

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to apply repeating pattern to my layout background, but when i start application, background is black.

I have implemented custom view from SurfaceView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/playGroundLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

background tile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tile"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

surface creation:

```
 public class PlayGroundActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_ground);
            RelativeLayout surface = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.playGroundLayout);
            surface.addView(new PlayGroundSurface(this));
        }
    }
```

surfaceView implementation:

```
public class PlayGroundSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private MainThread thread;

    public PlayGroundSurface(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private Bitmap scaled;
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void render(Canvas canvas) {

    }
}
```

mainThread class:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread
{
    private final static int MAX_FPS = 50;
    private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
    private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private PlayGroundSurface surface;
    private boolean running = false;

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, PlayGroundSurface playGroundSurface) {
        surface = playGroundSurface;
        holder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run)
    {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Canvas canvas;

        long beginTime;
        long timeDiff;
        int sleepTime;
        int framesSkipped;

        sleepTime = 0;

        while(running)
        {
            canvas = null;
            try
            {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (holder)
                {
                    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    framesSkipped = 0;
                    surface.draw(canvas);
                    surface.render(canvas);

                    timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;

                    sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                    if(sleepTime > 0)
                    {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){ }
                    }

                    while(sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS)
                    {
                        surface.updateAllItems();
                        sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                        framesSkipped++;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(canvas != null)
                {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i change layout root element from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout, it shows horizontal stripe of background. Seems like my RelativeLayout has zero dimensions.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: again, you should add your MainThread class to your post

Comment: added MainThread code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to remove the ImageView and set the background to the RelativeLayout directly

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/playGroundLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tryed to set directly to the root node, but got the same result. It behaves like surfaceView drawing method is not called. When i change class SurfaceView to View, it displays background correctly, but i want to implement it through SurfaceView

Comment: So the problem is with your SurfaceView, and you haven't shown it in your post.